# Firebird select comparing a timestamp with today in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, firebird

In VB.NET I'm running a Firebird SQL query:

```
select * from users where startdate < @SelectedDate
```

where startdate is a TimeStamp.

Using the Firebird .Net Provider in VB, I'm using a parameter for `@SelectedDate` of type  `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.TimeStamp` 
I would like the selection to work with both date and time.

The problem is that it just doesn't seem to work properly. 
With the column values being set to 03/05/2015 00:00:00 and the `@SelectedDate` being set to "Now" it should return the rows. It doesn't. Adding a day to `@SelectedDate` seems to work, which is interesting, but not much help.

Before I get involved with the alternative solutions - filtering after the SQL, or complicated SQL Extracts - I was wondering whether anyone knew if there is a solution?

When executed, it fails to return records that have a StartDate that are earlier than 'Now'.

Here's the code:

```
sSQL = " select * from blog where StartDate <= @thedate ";
MyConn.Open();
ds = New DataSet
Adaptor = New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataAdapter(sSQL, MyConn);
Adaptor.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
Adaptor.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@thedate",FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.TimeStamp).Value = Now;
Adaptor.Fill(ds)
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get an error? If so what exception + stacktrace. Also show the code you use to execute this. If you are using a string `NOW` as value, then that isn't going to work: that only works if it is literally in the query at parse time.

Comment: It executes fine, but the date selection produces an incorrect result.      sSQL = " select * from blog where isactive = 0  " &
                "    and StartDate <= @thedate "
       

     MyConn.Open()
            ds = New DataSet
            Adaptor = New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDataAdapter(sSQL, MyConn)
            Adaptor.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear()
            Adaptor.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@thedate", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.TimeStamp).Value = Now
            Adaptor.Fill(ds)

Comment: Please edit additional information into your question. Especially code is unreadable in comments. Also: describe what you mean with wrong result

Comment: As far as I can tell this should just work. I will see if I can reproduce with similar code.

Comment: I'm completely perplexed, so I've given up for now. I've just loaded the data into a dataset and filter it manually. I'll come back to it when I've time - thanks all.

Comment: I will try to reproduce this tomorrow and post an update. I also don't understand why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Finally I deleted the project, created a new one, added all the files,  and it worked fine.